# How to change Viewport Display properties for many objects at once?

Tags: 3d-view

I tried by selecting 3 objects and changing **Viewport Display** properties (Axis, Name) but it's only applied to the active object.

[image]

How to change Viewport Display properties for many objects at once ?

Comment: Do you try `Alt` + `Click` the button?

Comment: @XY That was it, thanks!!